# Snowflake CONVERT_TIMEZONE bug?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake, when converting some local dates to UTC and then back to local timezone using CONVERT_TIMEZONE function, the end result is off by one hour. For example:

```
ALTER SESSION SET TIMEZONE = 'Canada/Eastern';
select
cast('1949-04-24' as timestamp) as date_local -- because TIMEZONE = 'Canada/Eastern'
, convert_timezone('Canada/Eastern', 'UTC', '1949-04-24') as date_utc
, convert_timezone('UTC', 'Canada/Eastern', convert_timezone('Canada/Eastern', 'UTC', '1949-04-24')) as date_local1
```

The results are:

| DATE_LOCAL | DATE_UTC | DATE_LOCAL1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1949-04-24 **00:00:00.0** | 1949-04-24 05:00:00.0 | 1949-04-24 **01:00:00.0** |

I expect both DATE_LOCAL and DATE_LOCAL1 to be identical, however DATE_LOCAL1 is one hour off.
Is this expected? Am I missing something or there is a bug in the CONVERT_TIMEZONE function?

Comment: does adding another row, where the prior `date_utc` is reused, also covert wrong?
`, convert_timezone('UTC', 'Canada/Eastern', date_utc) as date_local2`

Comment: Yes, that is also wrong. This is what I tried:
with dates as
(
select
 cast('1949-04-24' as timestamp) as date_local -- because TIMEZONE = 'Canada/Eastern'
 , convert_timezone('Canada/Eastern', 'UTC', '1949-04-24') as date_utc
 , convert_timezone('UTC', 'Canada/Eastern', convert_timezone('Canada/Eastern', 'UTC', '1949-04-24')) as date_local1
)
select *, convert_timezone('UTC', 'Canada/Eastern', date_utc) as date_local2
from dates

Comment: Here is another date with the same issue: 1948-04-25
I suspect the issue is related somehow to DST since these problem dates are in April

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug. This is about Daylight Saving Time (DST). In 1949, DST started on Sunday, 24 April, 00:00. So when you convert it to UTC, It becomes 1949-04-24 05:00:00.0. When you convert it back, it becomes 01:00 because of DST, because it's the time that the clocks were turned forward one hour.

Comment: You are right, thank you! As explained here: https://torontooldnews.wordpress.com/2018/08/14/daylight-savings-time/ "In 1947, 1948, and 1949, for some reason, the city decided to set its clocks forward and back at midnight instead of 2 a.m."
See also: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/canada/toronto?year=1949
But shouldn't the conversion to UTC give 1949-04-24 04:00:00 in this case?

Comment: According to my understanding, at 00:00 (before the DST started), the TZ offset is UTC-5. So conversion gives 05:00. When you convert it back, the system uses UTC-4 as we know that DST started on Canada/Eastern.

Comment: Thank you for clarification, @Gokhan Atil! It makes sense now. 1949-04-24 00:00:00 is not a valid time (doesn't exist) since it becomes 1949-04-24 01:00:00. The same applies to all times between these two values. Thus, the CONVERT_TIMEZONE function does the conversion correctly.